# how to show items on top whose vote value is greater then others php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i hade made a PHP code that is showing all servers.. so I had a column called votes. I want to show array servers serial by serial like server1 has 10 votes and server2 has 9 votes so the server1 will be at the top and server2 will be after server1 how to do it? thank you.

here's the code I have..

```
$test = new Servers;

$test->additional_where("AND `private` = '0' AND `active` = '1' AND `highlight` = '0'");

$test->remove_pagination();

$test->display();
```

i had made a php code thats showing servers from mysql db perfectly.. i just wanted a thing like the server whom have top vote show him top and who has less vote like one server has 10 vote show him at top and second one has 20 show him after that server.. how to do it? thank you..

Comment: Hard to give clear answer without knowledge about Servers class structure. But I see here two ways to achieve this.
1. The easiest way is to sort it in your sql query ORDER BY votes, or whatever your votes column is
2. sort it in display method with ksort or usort depends on data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to sort the results.  You'll need to add something like below to your query:

```
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Comment: okay i had did this and its working than you guys